Experiencing 401 unauthorized error when sending date, day and thoughts to the backend
I'm experiencing a 401 unauthorized error. I am trying to post three things date, day and thoughts into my postgresSQL database using spring boot. When I hit the function from frontend it throws up the error. I'm sharing my security config class and controller along with the function code. Need some help in solving this.
** security config class : **

package com.diaries.diaryproject.SecurityConfig;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
     @Bean
     public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
          http
           .cors(cors -> cors.disable())  
           .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())  
          .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
              .requestMatchers("/user/add").permitAll()  
              .requestMatchers("/user/login").permitAll() 
              .requestMatchers("/data/save").permitAll() 
              .requestMatchers("/data/mydata").permitAll() 
//              .requestMatchers("/data/save").authenticated()
//              .requestMatchers("/data/mydata").authenticated()
              .anyRequest().authenticated()  
          );


      return http.build();
        }
}

** controller class : **

package com.diaries.diaryproject.UsersDataController;

import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.diaries.diaryproject.UsersDataModel.UsersData;
import com.diaries.diaryproject.UsersDataService.UsersDataService;
import com.diaries.diaryproject.model.Users;
import com.diaries.diaryproject.service.UsersService;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/data")
@CrossOrigin
public class UsersDataController {

    @Autowired
    private UsersDataService usersDataService;
    
    @Autowired
    private UsersService userService;
    
     @PostMapping("/save")
        public ResponseEntity<UsersData> saveData(@RequestBody UsersData data, Principal principal) {
           if (principal == null) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body(null);
            }
            // Retrieve user from database based on Principal username
            Users user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());
            data.setUser(user);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(usersDataService.saveUsersData(data));
        }

        @GetMapping("/mydata")
        public ResponseEntity<List<UsersData>> getMyData(Principal principal) {
              if (principal == null) {
                    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body(null);
                }
            Users user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());
            return ResponseEntity.ok(usersDataService.getUsersData(user));
        }
    
}

** handleDataSubmit function :**

const handleDataSubmit  = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const userData = {
      "date" : date,
      "day" : day,
      "thoughts" : thoughts
    }

   try{
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/data/save" ,
      {
        method : 'POST',
        headers : {
          'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        body : JSON.stringify(userData)
      }
    )
    if(response.status === 200){
      console.log("data submitted successfully")
     }
     else if(response.status === 401){
      console.log("an error has occured")
     }
     else{
    console.log("nothing")
     }
   }
   catch(error){
    console.log(error.message)
   }

  }



I assume that i must send something in the headers like some sort of a token but not sure what and where the token is.
